# Миграция с php 4 на 5

Tags: php, mysql

Скрипт работает только под PHP 4, в пятерке при сабминте не сохраняет значение чекбоксов. Не могу понять, в чем дело :(

```
if ($formdata) {
    foreach ($man as $key => $val)
        if ($val == "1") {
            $t = 1;
        } else {
            $t = 0;
        }
    mysql_query("UPDATE managers SET active='$t' WHERE number='$i'");
}

<form method="POST">
<input name="formdata" value="thisisform" type="hidden">
<input name="man[1]" value="1" type="checkbox" <?php $row=mysql_fetch_array($res); if($row["active"]==1) echo("checked")?>>

<input class="no" type="image" src="button.gif" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код во-первых очень дыряв. Например, здесь:

```
<input name="man[1]" value="1" type="checkbox" style="width:20px" ...php... >
```

Если более-менее "умный" пользователь додумается залезть в исходный код сайта и поменять значение чекбокса( вместо единицы поставит двойку, например ), то PHP-обработчик просто никак не сработает. **Второе:**

Почему бы ЭТО:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=$MAX; $i++) {
if ($man[$i]=="1") { $t=1; } else { $t=0; }
```

не заменить на ЭТО:

```
foreach($man as $key=>$val)
if ($val=="1") { $t=1; } else { $t=0; }
```

И,

```
...почему при сабминте не сохраняет значение чекбоксов...
```

потому что событие Submit отправляет данные, в вашем случае, PHP-обработчику( на сервер ) и после этого обновляет страницу. Если же вы хотите сохранить значения чекбоксов, то используйте сессии( $_SESSION )

Comment: Дело в том, что записи не уходят в базу базу данных. То есть в mysql строка "active" остается нулевой

Comment: А, вот так сразу и надо было писать. Попробуйте так:

     mysql_query("UPDATE managers SET active='$t' WHERE number='$i'")

Comment: Попробовала, без результата :( Да и ведь в 4 версии работало, сначала грешила на короткие теги..